# Is there a way to set up the "logpath" point to a specific log file(proxysql.log) in fail2ban, when the backend = systemd in jail.local file?

Tags: fail2ban

I am going to set up the fail2ban for monitoring the proxysql.log file and if detect some specific ERROR then send warning message on SLACK.
I am running on centOS 7.7,  followed by the documentation of installing and configuring, then only allow me to restart fail2ban when I set "backend = systemd", but the problem is the "logpath" will not point to any log files I set up. If I change the backend to any others, the "systemctl restart fail2ban" will always failed. I read some online, and install pynotify and gamin libs on server, still the same problem. So I am asking help from guys who can help me to solve the problem I had now.

All I have now is:

1. jail.conf set up one jail named proxysql
2. Have a filter in filter.d folder for failregex
3. Have an action in action.d folder for sending message to SLACK

Answer (score 0):

Setting `backend = systemd` for certain jail or default would completely ignore `logpath`, because the jails affecting by this will monitor systemd journal only.

> If I change the backend to any others, the "systemctl restart fail2ban" will always failed.

1. Well backend of which jail you're trying to change? You should do that only for jails that really have log-files (so don't do that for default section, if your other jails should monitor systemd-journal, otherwise you'd get error by start for each enabled jail for that fail2ban doesn't find a log-file).
2. Do you see any errors in fail2ban.log (or fail2ban journal, e. g. `journalctl -ru fail2ban`)?
3. You can also try to start it via client (`?sudo? fail2ban-client -vv start`) to get more info.
   Also check FAQ in our wiki - https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/Troubleshooting for possible answer.
4. As for backends: `pyinotify` expects also pyinotify module to be installed for python fail2ban running with (e. g. `fail2ban-python --version`). If it is 3.x, you'd install pyinotify for python3.
5. Did you try `backend = auto`? Because as fallback fail2ban will
   switch to `polling` backend (which is always available) and it'd
   error only if file (specified with `logpath`) does not exists.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tried your suggestion, but my problem is still there.

Comment: I created a new jail in jail.local named [proxysql] which is not one of default jail. I leave "backend=auto" in jail.conf, but if I don't use "backend=systemd" in jail.local or even in [proxysql] jail, the fail2ban cannot be started. I am using the command "systemctl status fail2ban.service && jiurnalctl -xe", then get "Failed to start Fail2Ban Service".

Comment: [proxysql]
#bantime = 1
#findtime = 600
enabled = true
port     = http, https, ssh, sshd
filter = proxysql
backend = polling
#journalmatch = /var/lib/proxysql/proxysql.log
action = slack-notify
logpath = /var/lib/proxysql/proxysql.log
#maxretry = 1

Comment: The main problem for me is I cannot switch backend to any other, only can use systemd. If I can switch it to "polling" or some others, I think the logpath = /var/lib/proxysql/proxysql.log can be customized by myself. Sorry I was not explained my problem very clear, but you also give me something I can try it.